# Git push from a previous commit

Tags: git, push, git-branch

I have several commit in a branch, but I notice that there was something wrong so I return (checkout) to a previous commit, and made some changes and now everything is fine.

But the problem is that I am not able to push because git want me to pull first, but I don't want to, because it will merge and I don't want to.

I just want my current local commit that will be the first or latest commit.

How is this possible?

Comment: Why can't you pull and when you merge with the pull, select your own changes?

Comment: Did you already push the incorrect commit?

Comment: Yes, i have already push the incorrect commit

Comment: You will need to either push with "force" option (but then, other people working on this project may/will be angry on you), or you can add an extra "undo" commit on top on the bad one. Check out the bad one, apply a undo/negating/rollbacking patch onto it (then you will be able to push it and bad code will evaporate(~) from remote repo), then take your corrections and rebase them onto curent head. Result will be: bad code removed, patches applied. As for the (~)evaporate -- no, actually it won't. History will know you pushed bad code and then that you removed it back.

Comment: However, if you don't know what I'm talking about, please wait until someone writes you a longer, more detailed walkthrough, or at least points you to some article about that. If you fail at any of the steps I mentioned above, you may screw something hard. Of course, there's almost nothing that couldn't be repaired, but if you mess up something, it will take more "arcane" knowledge to fix, and may/will leave you a really bad taste afterwards. Unnecessarily, if there is such word:)

Answer (score 1):

Just to turn @quetzalcoatl 's comment into an answer...

```
git push --force
```

...will move the `HEAD` for the branch in the remote to the current commit, even if that commit is before where the remote `HEAD` is currently pointed.

This works for undoing a recent commit even after `push`ing it. Use a `reset --soft` to move the current `HEAD` back, then a `push --force` to update the head to the remote.

Comment: git push -f origin